# Rails application and multiple database instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

can any one suggest good developemt approach to the website..

Hosted webapplicaion, with SAAS approach, different university when registering through the site, they should have their own instance of database to manage their details.

1) subdomain approach - X copies of application connecting to their own database, each copy of app will have different database connection in their yml file

2) One application,  with multiple database instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's better to have only one app runnig, instead of X copies, as you might end up in a "configuration hell" in which each uni has a different version of the app deployed.

One alternative that you haven't mentioned is mix of the two approaches, to have one application with subdomains, and each subdomain talks to a different schema. In this case you have only one app deployed and the data from each uni is kept in isolation from the others.

I'm building a small app (with the idea of reselling...maybe) which would benefit from this approach, if you want, we can join forces (:p) to build a small proof of concept.

Comment: thank you. how about the approach like (app.com/uni1, app.com/uni2) instead of going for subdomain apprach

Comment: Can you drop me a PM on twitter or github? (check my [details](http://stackoverflow.com/users/608820/augusto))